# Как заставить Visual Studio работать со свойствами в C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Visual Studio 2010 на попытку создать свойство у класса пишет:

> error C3813: a property declaration can only appear within the definition of a managed type

Но ведь C++ Builder всё работает, и никакого CLR эта среда не требует. Ставлю *enable CLR*. Вижу кучу ошибок запуска компилятора. Гуглю по каждой ошибке, отключаю все опции (нет чтобы вывалить сразу все, ругается на каждую опцию по одной, но ладно, это хоть бесит, но хотя бы решаемо). В итоге Студия перестаёт подчёркивать свойства в редакторе кода, но все ошибки компиляции остаются.

Я понимаю, что самый правильный совет в данной ситуации - вообще не использовать Visual Studio для программирования на C++, но у меня есть ученик, от которого это требуют в ВУЗе. Может, к ней хотя бы можно подключить нормальный сторонний компилятор?

```
class  rectangle
{
    private:
    double left;
    double top;
    double height;
    double width;

    double get_right();
    double get_bottom();
    public: // Открытые члены класса
    rectangle(); // Конструкторы
    rectangle(double left, double top,
        double height, double width);

    // Методы
    void move(double left, double top);
    void resize(double height, double width);

    // Свойства
    __property double Left = { read = left };
    __property double Top = { read = top };
    __property double Height = { read = height };
    __property double Width = { read = width };
    __property double Right = { read = get_right };
    __property double Bottom = { read = get_bottom };
};
```

Comment: А где в **стандарте** C++ есть такое понятие, как "свойства"? *Расширения* от создателя компилятора - это уже **не** С++. Так что самый правильный совет - для программирования на С++ не использовать ничего за пределами С++... И, само собой, ничего удивительного, что *расширения* в разных компиляторах несовместимы.

Comment: Можно к студии прикрутить toolkit от сибилдера, чтобы собирать его компилятором/линкером. Но если от ученика требуют использование VS, скорей всего ему не разрешат использовать свойства в классах.

Comment: В языке С++ нет и никогда не было никаких "свойств". Соответственно ни один из распространенных С++ компиляторов никаких "свойств" в С++ коде не поддерживает. Откуда они взялись в вашем учебнике? Вы уверены, что в учебнике речь идет именно о С++?

Comment: Это хороший вопрос... Когда я готовил курс, я специально проверял это, и включил туда раздел про свойства, предварительно убедившись, что это есть в стандарте. Интересно, где такое написано, если это в реальности оказалось не так?

Comment: @Modus, [свойства в MSVS2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfk0thd(v=vs.100).aspx), но, как уже говорили, это языковое расширение студии.

Comment: Добавил заголовочный файл класса, который использую для попытки настроить Студию для работы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В чистом С++ синтаксически нет такого понятия как "свойства" (функции, выглядящие как одно поле и проксирующие получение/установку значения). Компиляторы реализуют это кто во что горазд: вместо борландовского

```
 __property Type name = { read = getter, write = setter };
```

в Visual Studio [нужно писать](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfk0thd(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
 __declspec(property( get = getter, put = setter )) Type name;
```

Можно исправлять примеры руками. А можно написать макросы `PROP` и `AUTO_PROP`, определяющий тип компилятора и подставляющий правильный код (аналогично делается для read-only и write-only свойств):

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #define PROP(Type, name, setter, getter)                  \
        __declspec(property( get = getter, put = setter )) Type name;

    #define AUTO_PROP(Type, name)                             \
        private:                                              \
        Type _##name;                                         \
        Type get_##name() const { return _##name; }           \
        void set_##name(const Type& name) { _##name = name; } \
        public:  __declspec(property(                         \
                                get = get_##name,             \
                                put = set_##name ))           \
        Type name;
#elif defined(__BORLANDC__)
    #define PROP(Type, name, setter, getter)                  \
        __property Type name = { read = getter, write = setter };

    #define AUTO_PROP(Type, name)                             \
        private:                                              \
        Type _##name;                                         \
        Type get_##name() const { return _##name; }           \
        void set_##name(const Type& name) { _##name = name; } \
        public:  __property Type name  = {                    \
                        read=get_##name,                      \
                        write=set_##name };
#endif
```

Но все равно это не будет чистым С++ и другой тип компилятора такой код может не принять.
Другой вариант, который соберется любым компилятором, но для клиента свойство будет выглядеть как функция:

```
#define AUTO_PROP(Type, name)                       \
    private: Type _##name;                          \
    public:                                         \
    Type name() const { return _##name; }           \
    void name(const Type& name) { _##name = name; }
```

Объявляется все это так:

```
class Note {
public:
    PROP(int, id, getter, setter);
    AUTO_PROP(std::string, title);
    AUTO_PROP(std::string, content);

private:
    int getter() const;
    void setter(int id);
};
```

Comment: а че просто не выставить поле как публичное? У свойств основная фишка - можно код добавить на чтение/запись. А здесь это просто переменная класса через ненужные прослойки.

Comment: Ну, для вызывающего кода это всё равно выглядит как метод. Там же мякотка, что мы можем свойством сослаться как на поле, так и на метод, а в вызывающем коде это будет синтаксис обращения к полю. Так что это вообще не решение.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, это считается плохим дизайном. Со временем может потребоваться, скажем, валидация, логгирование, кэширование или еще какая-то побочная работа и тогда для публичного поля придется менять клиентский код. Оверхеда от "ненужных прослоек" не будет, если компилятор будет инлайнить аксессоры.

Comment: @free_ze я понимаю, что может понадобится, но ваши макросы этого не дают сделать - надо будет прописывать явно геттеры/сеттеры. Т.е. как ответ на вопрос - макросы не вариант.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, при использовании аксессоров (макросами или явно) клиентский код менять не придется. Это SOLID-круто-модно-молодежно.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, макрос в данном случае - это сахар, как автосвойства в C#. Если проводить аналогию, то там тоже придется переписывать свойство для частного случая.

Comment: @free_ze я пониманию прекрасно назначение геттеров/сеттеров, но у вас здесь макрос, который какбудто реализует свойства, но на самом деле ничего не делает, и работает также как если бы поле было публичным (притом принуждая пользоваться синтаксисом вызова методов).

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, "притом принуждая пользоваться синтаксисом вызова методов" - это позволяет переписать реализацию аксессоров не изменяя клиентский код.

Comment: @free_ze Клиентский код как раз и надо будет переписать с использования свойств на использование методов. Какое отношение это будет иметь к вопросу? Свойства, это когда можно будет написать: `object.field = 42` и будет вызван сеттер из `object`.

Comment: @Modus, где "там"? В Java (JavaBeans), например, свойства реализуются через явные get/set методы и приватное поле.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, вот чтобы такой необходимости не было и существует такое понятие как _свойства_

Comment: @free_ze "там" это в C++ Builder, естественно.

Comment: @Modus, обновил ответ.

Comment: Ага, спасибо. Теперь заработало. Правда, публичные свойства Студия требует реализовывать через публичные методы и поля, но хотя бы тестовый пример скомпилировался и заработал.